# Form submit buttons not posting in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I have a form that was working not too long ago.  I haven't made any changes to the view and only a small superficial change to the post method, yet now whenever I hit the submit button it doesn't even call the post method. Here is my view code:

```
@model MinimumInventory.WebUI.ViewModels.ProductInfoWithNote


<head>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#UseForecast').click(function () {
                var $this = $(this).is(':checked');

                if ($this) {
                    $('#MinimumOnHandQuantity').attr("disabled", "disabled")
                    $('#ForecastMultiplier').removeAttr("disabled");
                } else {
                    $('#MinimumOnHandQuantity').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('#ForecastMultiplier').attr("disabled", "disabled")
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<h2>Create Product Info</h2>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "MinimumProductInfoList")
</div>

<h4>@(ViewBag.Message ?? string.Empty)</h4>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ItemCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UseForecast, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UseForecast, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UseForecast, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MinimumOnHandQuantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MinimumOnHandQuantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MinimumOnHandQuantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ForecastMultiplier, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ForecastMultiplier, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ForecastMultiplier, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MaximumOHandQuantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MaximumOHandQuantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MaximumOHandQuantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MinimumOrderQuantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MinimumOrderQuantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MinimumOrderQuantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" name="create" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" name="createAndAnother" value="Create and Another" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

and my post method is follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateMinimumProductInfo(ProductInfoWithNote productInfoWithNote)
{
```

I don't think I need to show any more of the post method because it doesn't even call the method.  The view name is CreateMinimumProductInfo so I don't need to explicitly type out the name.    As you can see I have two separate submit buttons and they were both working last week.  What else could be causing this?

Comment: What error do you see in the browser's console?
Is the GET action that loads the view also called `CreateMinimumProductInfo`? Was the `checkbox` logic present when it was previously working?

Comment: @adiga Yes to both of the latter questions.  I don't see anything in the console window.  No error, no text.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is with the `jquery` code. Some client-side validation is failing. Is there a `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` in your Layout?. If yes, jquery reference in the view seems unnecessary and adding jquery more than once causes issue.

Comment: @adiga, I tried also with the Jquery commented out and it still didn't work.

Comment: @adiga I have it in my original post. `@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}`

Comment: That is the jquery validation bundle. Is `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` present in the layout? Also it's worth noting that disabled form elements are not submitted on `POST`. You should also move all the `scripts` inside `@section Scripts {}` block.

Comment: @adigam, I didn't know that disabled items do not post but I don't need the disabled ones to post, so that isn't a problem. I just added the `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")' to the view.

Comment: @adiga, I added that and no change.

Comment: You don't need to add the `~/bundles/jquery` and `jquery-latest.min.js`  if it's already added in the layout. Check the console and network tab. Make sure all form elements have valid inputs. With the info provided in the question, I can't help any further :(